# Append tr in table in IE

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table structure:

```
<table id="tableId">
 <tbody id="tbodyId">

  <tr id="trId1">
   <td>id</td><td>name</td>
  </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

I am adding new row with simple Javascript like this:

```
var itemsContainer = dojo.byId('tbodyId');
itemCount++; //it will give id to tr i.e. trId2

var newItemNode = document.createElement('tr');
newItemNode.setAttribute("id", 'trId' + itemCount);
newItemNode.innerHTML ='<td>id</td><td>anotherName</td>';

itemsContainer.appendChild(newItemNode);
```

All works fine in Firefox but row is not appended in IE. New table after it in Firefox becomes:

```
<table id="tableId">
 <tbody id="tbodyId">

  <tr id="trId1">
   <td>id</td><td>name</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="trId2">
   <td>id</td><td>anotherName</td>
  </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

I saw other codes and help. I only want one tbody in this table with simple Javascript no jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are special functions for creating table cells ( and rows ) eg - insertRow for rows and insertCell for cells - it works in all browsers

```
var newItemNode = itemsContainer.insertRow( itemsContainer.rows.length - 1 );
newItemNode.setAttribute("id", 'trId' + itemCount);

var cell = newItemNode.insertCell( 0 );
cell.innerHTML = 'id';
```

...

PS. I think DOJO Framework have something for inserting rows and cells

Comment: you are right insertRow for rows and insertCel works for all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

First off, [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CpGHP/) works fine in FF6 & IE8

Make sure that your real html has the proper markup. Your example shows a closing `tbody` element without the slash

```
  <tr id="trId2">
   <td>id</td><td>anotherName</td>
  </tr>

 <tbody> <!-- This line should be </tbody> -->
```

IE is inconsistant with its acceptance of bad markup.

In addition, code like this:

```
var newItemNode = document.createElement('tr');
newItemNode.setAttribute("id", 'trId' + itemCount);
newItemNode.innerHTML ='<td>id</td><td>anotherName</td>';
```

Is exactly the sort of code that toolkits like dojo (and its smarter cousin, jQuery) are built to avoid. I suspect the code for creating a new row are different in the version of IE you're testing on.

Comment: </tbody> is closed in my code. It was a typo in question. Code I am checking is same.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<html>
<script language = "javascript">

function kk()
{
    var itemsContainer = document.getElementById("tbodyId");

    var newItemNode = document.createElement('tr');
    newItemNode.setAttribute("id", 'trId' + 1);
    var newCellItem1 = document.createElement('td');
    newCellItem1.innerHTML = "id";
    var newCellItem2 = document.createElement('td');
    newCellItem2.innerHTML = "anotherName";
    newItemNode.appendChild(newCellItem1);
    newItemNode.appendChild(newCellItem2);
    itemsContainer.appendChild(newItemNode);

}
</script>
<table id="tableId">
 <tbody id="tbodyId">

  <tr id="trId1">
   <td>id</td><td>name</td>
  </tr>


 </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value = "heihei" onclick = "kk();"></input>
</html>
```